# Get foreground CHILD window

Tags: delphi, skype, foreground, window-handles

Whenever Skype is in **Default View**, the `TConversationWindow`'s become children of the `tSkMainForm` Window.

I am having problems finding out which `TConversationWindow` is active - however it's not like an MDI interface - only **one** `TConversationWindow` is visible, like if it was a **Tab/Page**.

When I do `GetForegroundWindow`, Skype's MainForm handle is returned (`tSkMainForm`). Is there any way that I can get the foreground `TConversationWindow` within Skype?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541629/detecting-whether-skype-is-in-compact-view-or-default-view) of mine has screenshots of Skype's Default View, if you need it. :)

**EDIT**: Here is a screenshot of the Winspector Hierachy:

[image]

**EDIT2**: I tried going thru the windows like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  function GetClassName(Handle: HWND): String;
  var
  Buffer: array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
  begin
  Windows.GetClassName(Handle, @Buffer, MAX_PATH);
  Result := String(Buffer);
  end;
Var
 Wnd: HWND;
 SkypeWnd: HWND;
begin
 SkypeWnd := FindWindow('tSkMainForm',nil);

 Wnd := GetTopWindow(SkypeWnd);

 while (GetClassName(Wnd) <> 'TConversationForm') and (Wnd <> 0) and (not IsWindowVisible(Wnd)) do
 begin
   Wnd := GetNextWindow(Wnd,GW_HWNDNEXT);
 end;

 Label1.Caption := GetClassName(Wnd)+' - '+GetHandleText(wnd);

end;
```

The above is supposed to find the visible window, however when I debug it, it never enters the Begin End within the While loop, and Label1 displays "TChromeMenu - ChromeToolbar". When I remove the IsWindowVisible check, it atleast finds a TConversationForm. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT3**: By placing the IsWindowVisible and getClassName check inside the loop, and break when true, I managed to do it. :)

Comment: What about `EnumerateWindows` or FindWindow to get it?

Comment: I think you have to use z-order of the child windows to determine which one is on top.

Comment: There is no such function "EnumerateWindows", `FindWindow` is not applicable here too. Best bet is `GetWindow(.., GW_HWNDFIRST)` call.

Comment: @David - `FindWindow` and `FindWindowEx` does not return the expected `TConversationWindow`. How would `EnumWindows` help me in this situation? @ain - How would I do that? :)

Comment: @Downvoter - The first parameter, would that be the parent window?

Comment: @David - The window is a child of `tSkMainForm`

Comment: @David - please see edited post, I added a screenshot of Winspector :)

Comment: @David **All the same if it's children you want call EnumChildWindows.ChildWindows** - That will list the children, but AFAIK it wont give me the active one?

Comment: Define what you mean by active.

Comment: @David - I mean "the window I am currently looking at", because in **default view**, you can only see one `TConversationForm` at a time. :)

Comment: @Jeff It depends then on the Skype implementation but it's easy to guess how it would be done.  Either the active one is above the others in the z-order.  Or, more likely, the inactive conversation windows are all invisible.  Easy enough to check which it is.

Comment: @David - So how do I compare? Get next window untill I find one that is visible?

Comment: EnumChildWindows and stop when you have one with the right class and that's visible. Maybe.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1060/discussion-between-jeff-and-david-heffernan)

Comment: @David - I edited my OP with some code, that is behaving weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By placing the IsWindowVisible and getClassName check inside the loop, and break when true, I managed to do it. :)